# Check if any argument matches using helper func

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this:

```
ql_match_arg(){
    declare -a my_array=$1
    for var in "${my_array[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$var" == "$2" ]]; then
          return 0;
        fi
    done
}


ql_ls () {
   local my_array=( "$@" ); ql_json=$(ql_match_arg my_array[@] '--json' && echo "yes")
   ql_pid="$$" ql_json="$ql_json" ql_node_ls_all
}
```

what I am trying to do is create a helper function (ql_match_arg) which can be used by other functions to determine in any argument matches a given name. In this case, I want to find out if the --json flag is passed as any argument to `ql_ls`.

The problem I have is that it's not looping over my_array - something is wrong with my code - either I am not passing the array to `ql_match_arg` correctly, or something else is wrong.

Comment: I think this basically has the answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/674333/how-to-pass-an-array-as-function-argument

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I have is that it's not looping over my_array

With this:

```
declare -a my_array=$1
```

You are creating an array with just *one* value: `$1`, the *first* argument passed to your script. So there is not much to loop over there.

If you want *all* arguments, try:

```
declare -a my_array=$@
```

Instead.

Comment: yeah thanks, I think this has the answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/674333/how-to-pass-an-array-as-function-argument